# Null Object when closing voice recognition dialog

Tags: java, android

Hello am crating an app that opens social networks with voice recognition,the app is working well,but if the voice recognition dialog pops up and i press back button without saying anything the app force close, part of the code that logcat is pointing to :

```
if (firstWord.equals("open")) {
            PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            List<PackageInfo> packs = packageManager
                    .getInstalledPackages(0);
            int size = packs.size();
            boolean uninstallApp = false;
            boolean exceptFlg = false;
            for (int v = 0; v < size; v++) {
                PackageInfo p = packs.get(v);
                String tmpAppName = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(
                        packageManager).toString();
                String pname = p.packageName;
                tmpAppName = tmpAppName.toLowerCase();
                if (tmpAppName.trim().toLowerCase().
                        equals(secondWord.trim().toLowerCase())) {

                    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
                    Intent appStartIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pname);


                    if (null != appStartIntent) {
                        try {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "That App is not a Social One ;-) )",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }  // end of open app code
```

I tried to add `}else{`but it didn't work,

Logcat

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
            at mrad4tech.com.test.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:94)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3535)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3582)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5223)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
09-25 20:12:26.265    7041-7041/mrad4tech.com.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: mrad4tech.com.test, PID: 7041
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1234, result=0, data=null} to activity {mrad4tech.com.test/mrad4tech.com.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3539)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3582)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5223)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
            at mrad4tech.com.test.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:94)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3535)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3582)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5223)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

FULL CODE

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private
    static
    final
    int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private static final String TAG = String.valueOf(1);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return
                true;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.button1:
                startVoiceRecognitionActivity();

                break;

        }


    }


    public void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getClass()
                .getPackage().getName());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 5);
        startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        String wordStr = null;
        String[] words = null;
        String firstWord = null;
        String secondWord = null;
        if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE
                && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> matches = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            wordStr = matches.get(0);
            words = wordStr.split(" ");
            firstWord = words[0];
            secondWord = words[1];
        }

        if (firstWord.equals("open")) {
            PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            List<PackageInfo> packs = packageManager
                    .getInstalledPackages(0);
            int size = packs.size();
            boolean uninstallApp = false;
            boolean exceptFlg = false;
            for (int v = 0; v < size; v++) {
                PackageInfo p = packs.get(v);
                String tmpAppName = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(
                        packageManager).toString();
                String pname = p.packageName;
                tmpAppName = tmpAppName.toLowerCase();
                if (tmpAppName.trim().toLowerCase().
                        equals(secondWord.trim().toLowerCase())) {

                    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
                    Intent appStartIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pname);


                    if (null != appStartIntent) {
                        try {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "That App is not a Social One ;-) )",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }  // end of open app code
        else {

        }


    }





}
```

I tried to add }else{ Toast.makeText.....} but didnt work

Comment: `if (null != appStartIntent)` shouldn't this be `if(appStartIntent != null)` might not matter idk.  Also what line of code is Line 94?

Comment: Thanks the guy below helped i appreciate your try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE
                && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> matches = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            wordStr = matches.get(0);
            words = wordStr.split(" ");
            firstWord = words[0];
            secondWord = words[1];
        } // This ends above if

        if (firstWord.equals("open")) {
```

It seems to me that you continue with `if (firstWord.equals...` even if result code wasn't `RESULT_OK`. So you always check if `firstWord` equals something, even if you don't actually assign anything to it.

Edit: To avoid confusion and overly indented code, you can simply do

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      if (requestCode != VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE || resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
          return; // don't do anything
      }
      // Assume you have all data
      // ...
    }
```

Comment: i removed " } // This ends above if" and put it at last

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If you like the answer consider upvoting it too

Comment: Please man,the app is to open social networks when saying open whatsapp (Whatsapp is an example ) ,when i say something else than Open the app crashes

Comment: logcat said that the error is at 
            secondWord = words[1];

Comment: You need to see what's inside `words` varable. I don't quite know what recognition api returns, but you could probably see `if (words.length >= 2)`, and if not, treat is as if result was not ok, and return from the method

Comment: Hmmm,didnt work,or understood tried it the wrong way..ANW Thanks alot,i cant vote up i've already created my acount,but you can ;)